# How to get the Customers Increment Id in PDFs

Tags: customer, pdf

I changed the table "eav_entity_store" in my DB so i get a customer_increment_id like this "2015_00001".
This works fine and every new customer get this id (2015_xxxxx) in "customer_entity.increment_id".

The normal value for this colmn is NULL and the system use entity_id for the customer_id.

Now i want do print this increment_id in my invoice/shipping/creditmemo-PDFs instead the normal customer_id.
Is there an easy way to get the increment_id from the customer_id?

I have the place in my Abstract.php to print the id, but i don´t find the value for the increment_id. I only got the normal custumer_id [ $order->getCustomerId() ].

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution

I directly get the increment_id from the DB

```
$newConnection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$tablePrefix = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix();
$query = $newConnection->select()->from($tablePrefix . 'customer_entity')
         ->where('entity_id = ' . $order->getCustomerId(). ' AND store_id = ' . $order->getStoreId());
$row = $newConnection->fetchRow($query);
$customerid = $row['increment_id'];
```